# 'what is android:theme="@*android........'' please help Error in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" />
```

Error in android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
could not be resolved.

it is from the manifest

Comment: remove that * and try with which i have post as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to remove the asterisk (*) between @ and android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar ?

Should simply be: `android: theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`. You have added * after @ syb

Replace

```
android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: no my code is perfect * works in the rest of my apps

Answer (score 1):

Add theme to you activity in manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".activityName"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".activityName"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Comment: no my code is perfect it is something with my gradle

Comment: is there any error showing?